# Mysql link table columns varchar

Tags: mysql, hyperlink, foreign-keys, varchar

I'm making a database which includes artists, albums and songs. I have a table for artists (artists), for albums (albums) and for songs (songs). The album table has a foreign key from artists, the artist_id so I don't have to write the artists' names over and over again.

Now I want to add songs. I exported tag values of my albums to csv files. These I imported into mysql. That's the songs table, it includes: title, artist_name, album_name, time.

Now I want the songs to be linked to the corresponding album. So the column album_name from songs is album_name from albums. I don't know how to link them, as far as I know foreign keys need int. In albums there is album_id but that can't be included in songs, if I wanted to I would have to put them in manually, that's a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refactor your `songs` table and replace `artist_name` with `artist_id` and `album_name` with `ablum_id`, which have a foreign key constraint on `artists` and `albums` tables respectively

Another way of looking at is:

the `albums` table is essentially a junction table between `artists` and `songs`. You could have called the table `artists_songs` to reflect the relationship.

In this case, your junction table should have both `artist_id` and `song_id`.

So the relationships will be

1. `artists` have many `albums` (or `artists_songs`), have many `songs` via `albums`
2. `albums` have many `songs`, belong to `artists`
3. `songs` belongs to `albums`, belongs to `artists` via `albums`